# ambiguous column name, my WHERE statement is already taken up for other purposes

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause

So i have this problem where i need an INNER JOIN to connect my imagetable to my product table, and i've already tried to specify each coloumn name with a connection to the tables as you can see below. When it comes to my WHERE statement, thats where it gets tricky. Since i need to save my ProductID as a variable called pid for other codebehind purposes.

```
SELECT * FROM ProductTBL p
INNER JOIN ImageTBL img on p.ProductID = img.ProductID 
WHERE (ProductID = @pid)
```

When i run this code it will tell me ProductID is an ambiguous column name and when i try
to specify my Where statement even further like this:

```
WHERE (p.ProductID = @pid)
```

It will give me another error telling me that no data is bound to my certain rows from which i'm taken out data from. This error is only there when i don't specify the Where statement like the one above.

Any input at all will be greatly appreciated :)

PS: im running MSSQL if that has anything to say.

Comment: What is the exact error you get when you try the second variant? Why do you have () around the element of your `WHERE`-clause?

Comment: *no data is bound* Doesn't sound like an MSSQL error.

Comment: `When you run this code` where? Also please list specific error messages instead of paraphrasing them. I suspect that part of the problem is the `SELECT *` - you now have two columns in the output named `ProductID` (and maybe others). So if something higher up the stack is trying to consume this result set, I can see where an ambiguous column name comes from. What is the point of including both? You might consider [not using `SELECT *`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).

Comment: Anders UP - A weird habit i guess, i've tried and remove them. If they are there or not doesn't make any difference. Deruijter - Yes, i've specified my pid as a protected string and got it to work the way i want. It's not that which is causing any problems.  

@Aaron - Yes, it may very well be the * that wasn't defined well enough. I've tried to specify each coloumn in my product table, as people suggested like: p.ProductID, p.ProductName and so on, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: And did you try @Ian's advice? Your "no data is bound" error seems to stem from your application, not SQL Server. So if we only know about the query, and that query works fine from SSMS, there's not much we can do to help you debug your application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two ways of doing this. The 2nd way is probably the recommended way (it should run quicker).

Way 1)

Run it in a two step statement. I don't think you can use the * in the inner SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.ProductID, [other needed fields]
    FROM ProductTBL p
    INNER JOIN ImageTBL img on p.ProductID = img.ProductID
    ) as x
WHERE (ProductID = @pid)
```

The inner SELECT p.ProductID says to explicitly return the ProductID from the ProductTBL. That ProductID field can then be used in your WHERE statement because it's in the outer SQL statement.

Way 2)

Put the "WHERE" criteria as part of the join

```
SELECT *
FROM ProductTBL p
INNER JOIN ImageTBL img on p.ProductID = img.ProductID AND p.ProductID = @pid
```

Answer (score 1):

The "ambiguous column name" message is a SQL Server error, and you fixed it by specifying "WHERE p.ProductID = @pid".  Yes, you need the p. in front of ProductID, because ImageTBL also has a column with the same name.

The "no data is bound" error is not coming from SQL.  You now have a correct SQL statement, but it is apparently returning no records, at least for the value of @pid that you are running it with.

You are calling this from an application that is trying to do something with the data, right?  That is where the "no data is bound" error is coming from.

You can separate the two parts of your problem by running your SQL statements in a SQL Server Management Studio query window, and plugging in your desired value for @pid.  Then you can run your application in debug mode, and check whether it is receiving the same data you see in Management Studio.  Here's one guess:  your application is not passing @pid correctly, and the SQL statement is returning records where p.ProductID = ''.  See if that's what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue with your code. Try to run the query with hard core value of product ID and run it in the database console.

It doesn't appear to be a database issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well its the where statment that has the problem. You need to prefix your productID with your table alias. Table alias' are good, I've no doubt you have realised that when you type SELECT * From MyTable T, and then go back to choose your columns, you get an intellisnce list of columns when you replace * by T. Aliasing tables is always good. Say you have two tables T1 and T2 and Columns C1, C2, C3 in T1 and C4, C5, C6 in T2. You script your stored procedure and it works. Sometime later somone comes along and adds c column named C2 to T2, then your procedure will probably break if you have not prfixed the table name on the columns. So even if there is no current ambiguity and you never change your stored proc, using prefixed is always more robust.

Its always a good idea to explicitly state you columns rather than using *, because once again adding columns can break your proc and also if you have a column name incorrect, SSMS will underline it with a little red squigle.